# JAVAFX - Windows rights calling

Tags: java, methods, javafx, rights

I have two good working windows (main window, first window) in seperate .java files, at the same package.

The program handles, if I call the the First window (from the main), the Main stays in the background. The only problem is that I still can use the main window if I click there, and create infinity first windows.

One solution is to shut down the Main window, to avoid clicking there again, but I would like to keep there. In order to make the solution I need a code which makes the background window somehow disabled until I click something in the First Window.
 But to do that I need to give the rights to the "handler.java" to operate with the main.

Anybody has any idea how to do that?

Let me show you the 2 java file's methods:

Main.java:

```
  public class program extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage main) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainwindow.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    main.setScene(scene);
    main.setTitle("Main);
    main.setWidth(800);
    main.setHeight(600);
    main.setResizable(false);

          main.show();
```

First.java

```
    public void first() throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("first.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage first = new Stage();     
    first.setScene (scene);
    first.setTitle("Köszöntjük az Útiokosban!");
    first.setWidth(400);
    first.setHeight(200);
    first.setResizable(false);

          first.show();

}
```

Comment: Did you think about making your first window a modal dialog?

Comment: Is it difficult to change it to modal? Why would it be better for me?

Comment: Modal dialogs prevent any access to the parent stage, while the dialog is open. You can also make your dialog prevent any access to all other windows of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the advisory in the chapter "Modality" in this link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Stage.initModality`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initModality-javafx.stage.Modality-) to make one of your `Stage`s modal (blocking).

Note: You need to set the modality before displaying the `Stage`.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

 If I could give 2 "right answer" mark, I'd give the other one.